# "Connection timed out: connect" while deploying java application to azure web app container

Tags: java, azure-web-app-service

I have installed azure plugin for eclipse, created a sample java application in my local machine and tried to deploy it to azure web app container from eclipse. But it gives error" Deploy web app error. Connection timed out: connect.

What could be the issue? Please help

Thank you

Comment: What connection could it be? SQL or HTTP? Show us the StackTrace from the logs....

Comment: It is a simple helloworld application that is developed locally in eclipse.  Installed azure plugin for eclipse to directly deploy it to azure from eclipse. I have tried the same thing on the following tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-get-started-java. As per in the document, when i clicked on the deploy button after configuring resource group,jdk, app service plan, it tries to deploy. But after some time it gives connection timeout error

Comment: @Aswathy how long did it take before  the connection timeout error appeared? Could you post the  relevant screenshots?

Comment: It takes almost 30 seconds. then timedout error appears.

Comment: @Aswathy Any Progress?

Comment: Did the Resource-Group get created?  Did the app-service-plan get created?  On mine, I get the resource-group and app-service-plan, but get this message on the app-service itself.

Comment: I do not agree this is a duplicate.  This is a specific eclipse plugin (Azure) issue, and NOT a generic connection issue.

Comment: So if your app-service-plan got created and your app-service got created..............it may be an FTP issue.  I think the actual files (jsp,etc) get pushed out there by ftp.  Try to use an independent tool (like filezilla or winscp) to connect using the ftp credentials.  You can see them in the eclipse azure plugin on the "deploy web app" screen. THere is a "show ftp deployment credentials" to get the username/pwd/host.

Comment: I cannot add an answer.  So for future readers.  I think this is more about simple ftp connections than the Azure plugin itself.  If you get a microsoft tool called "PortQryUI.exe, an add on User Interface utility for PortQry", you can ping your ftp site (on port 21).  If you see FILTERED, it probably means your network has some kind of filtering/blocking on that port.  This little microsoft tool takes username/pwd out of the equation and just tests the site/port.......I figured this out the hard way.  (After I tried filezilla and winscp and they both failed).

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not able to find a way to "undo" the "duplicate question" tag.

Comment: @Raedwald This question is not a duplicate IMHO.  This is specific to an eclipse/azure plugin.  Not a "java.io" package/code issue.

Comment: If you do not think this question is a duplicate, you need to edit your question to include a link to the "non duplicate" question and explain why it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Your edited question should show that the provided advice in the other question did not help you. As it is, your question includes no evidence that you have done any investigation of the problem at all. It just looks like you got an error message you did not understand and gave up.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you are not behind a **firewall** or a **VPN client** or **proxy**.

This leads to the `Connection timed out: connect` when you are deploying your web app to azure.

Please check `Eclipse` proxy setting folow the `window-->preferences-->general-->network connections.`

Comment: I'm upvoting this because it would be the other issue.  (Your network has a proxy setup or something).  Future readers, please see my comment on the question about FTP port blockage.